# "Will you be at home tomorrow?" and "Are you going to be at home tomorrow?". What is the difference?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Can't undrestand what is the real difference between *"Will you be at home tomorrow?"* and *"Are you going to be at home tomorrow?"*. Both variants are grammatically correct. Maybe it is some meaning difference? Help me please to find out.

Comment: Have you heard them used differently?

Comment: I imagined some situation when I need to ask question like that and found two possibilities to do that. So I am not sure that they are equal. I have never met *"Are you going to be at home tomorrow?"* in real life, but as I think it could be used...

Comment: Without some emphasis / stress that might result from a specific context (absent here), those should be read as interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer! Do you mean that emphasis should be placed by voice or context?

Comment: I will be home tomorrow, but I will not be "at home to visitors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are largely interchangeable.

But as a rule of thumb, if you're asking a neutral question, go with *Will you be at home tomorrow?*. But if you're grilling someone on their plans, go with *Are you going to be at home tomorrow?*.